# Coping with misleading error messages of the Swift compiler (context dependence, type inference)

Tags: xcode, swift, compiler-errors

While the Swift compiler (Xcode 7.2) seems perfectly correct in diagnosing an error for some source text equivalent to the following, it took long to detect the actual error made. Reason: the programmer needs to look *not* at the text marked, but elsewhere, thus mislead, wondering why an optional string and a non-optional string can not be operands of `??`...

```
struct Outer {
    var text : String
}

var     opt : String?
var context : Outer


context = opt ?? "abc"
```

Obviously, the last line should have had `context.text` as the variable to be assigned. This is diagnosed:

> ```
> confusion2.swift:9:19: error: binary operator '??' cannot be applied\
>                                 to operands of type 'String?' and 'String'
>     context = opt ?? "abc"
>               ~~~ ^  ~~~~~
> ```

The message is **formally** correct. (I am assuming that type checking the left hand side establishes an expected type (`Outer`) for the right hand side, and this, then, renders the expression as not working, type-wise.) Taken literally, though, the diagnosis is wrong, as is seen when fixing the left hand side: `??` can be applied to operands of type `String?` and `String`.

Now, if this is as good as it gets, currently, in terms of compiler messages, what are good coping strategies? Is remembering

1. Type inference!
2. Context!
3. …

a start? Is there a more systematical approach? A check list?

**Update** (I'm adding to the list as answers come in. Thanks!)

1. break statements apart, so as to have several lines checked separately (@vacawama)
2. Beware of optionals (such as values got from dictionaries), see `testSwitchOpt` below

**Another one**

```
enum T {
    case Str(String)
    case Integer(Int)
}

func testSwitchOpt(x : T?) -> Int {
    switch x {
    case .Integer(let r): return r
    default: return 0
    }
}
```

The compiler says

> ```
> optandswitch.swift:8:15: error: enum case 'Integer' not found in type 'T?'
>        case .Integer(let r): return r
> ```

A fix is to write `switch x!` (or a more cautious `let`), so as to make type checking address the proper type, I guess.

I could, perhaps should, file some report at Apple, but the issue seems to represent a recurring subject—I have seen this with other compilers—and I was hoping for some general and re-usable hints, if you don't mind sharing them.

Answer (score 3):

Swift's type inference system is great in general, but it can lead to very confusing to outright wrong error messages.

When you get one of these Swift error messages that makes no sense, a good strategy is to break the line into parts.  This will allow Swift to return a better error message before it goes too far down the wrong path.

For example, in your case, if you introduce a temporary variable, the real problem becomes clear:

```
// context = opt ?? "abc"
let temp = opt ?? "abc"
context = temp
```

Now the error message reads:

> Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Outer'